# XML to SQL Server mappings program

Tags: c#, .net, xml, mapping

In summary, I am trying to write a .NET program that allows the user to load in an XML file and a SQL Server database to then create mappings (for later use) between the XML nodes of the file and the different tables and columns of the DB. The idea would be too, then, make another program that would read the generated mappings file and an XML file with the same structure. So the mappings can be used to insert the data into the DB.

The program should be able to manage nested loops and multiple tables mappings. For example, say we want to *parse* the following XML Demo file into 3 different tables `Order`, `Customer` and `Item`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <OrderId>1</OrderId>
        <OrderNumber>1001</OrderNumber>
        <Customer>
            <CustomerId>1</CustomerId>
            <Name>John Smith</Name>
            <Address>123 Main St</Address>
            <City>Anytown</City>
            <State>CA</State>
            <Zip>12345</Zip>
        </Customer>
        <Items>
            <Item>
                <ItemId>1</ItemId>
                <Name>Widget A</Name>
                <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                <Price>10.00</Price>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <ItemId>2</ItemId>
                <Name>Widget B</Name>
                <Quantity>10</Quantity>
                <Price>20.00</Price>
            </Item>
        </Items>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

The tables' structures are the following:

`Order`:

- `OrderID`
- `OrderNumber`
- `CustomerID`

`Customer`:

- `CustomerID`
- `Name`
- `Address`
- `City`
- `State`
- `Zip`

`Item`:

- `ItemID`
- `OrderID`
- `Name`
- `Quantity`
- `Price`

As you can see, some fields like `OrderID` and `CustomerID` can be found in different tables, the program should allow the user to map the same node path to different destinies.

These are some of the doubts I have:

1. What's the best way to base my mappings on, the XML itself or instead, generate an XSD based on that XML and use that.
2. What should the data structure be like? I have a basic one already but I'm not confident it would hold its own against nested elements and such.
3. My idea behind the UI is to have two comboboxes that allow the user to select a table and a column, then select a node and generate a mapping from there. The doubt is, the nodes should be loaded in as a TreeView, ListBox or someother control?

I have many other doubts, but I feel like a great deal of them would be solved based on these 3. Also, here's the code I have so far, it's not at all completed and it's totally a subject of change.

Thank you in advance.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="XSD_Mapper.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XSD_Mapper"
        xmlns:avalonEdit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="720" Width="1280">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <GroupBox Header="Configurations" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="10">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Content="XML File" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <TextBox Name="xmlSource" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Browse" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,10,0" Click="SelectXmlFile_Click"/>

                <Label Content="Connection String" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <TextBox Name="connectionString" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Content="Configure" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,10,0" Click="SelectDatabase_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Parsing" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
            <TabControl>

                <TabItem Header="Editor XSD">
                    <avalonEdit:TextEditor
                        Name="textEditor"
                        SyntaxHighlighting="XML"
                        FontFamily="Consolas"
                        FontSize="10pt"
                        ShowLineNumbers="True"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                        />
                </TabItem>


                <TabItem Header="Mapping">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <Label Content="Table: " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <ComboBox Width="200" Height="20" Margin="5,0,10,0" Name="tableSel" SelectionChanged="tableSel_SelectionChanged"/>
                            <Label Content="Column: " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <ComboBox Width="200"  Height="20" Margin="5,0,10,0" Name="columnSel"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <TreeView Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Name="xmlNodes">

                        </TreeView>
                        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Add Mapping" Width="120" Height="20" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="Save File" Width="120" Height="20" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                        <!--
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20">
                            <Button Name="loopRootNode" Content="Loop Root Node" Margin="0,0,0,50" Click="LoopRootNode_Click"/>
                            <CheckBox Name="isPrimaryKeyCheckbox" Content="Is Primary Key" Margin="0,0,0,50"/>

                            <CheckBox Name="isForeignKeyCheckbox" Content="Is Foreign Key" Click="isForeignKeyCheckbox_Click"/>
                            <Label Content="Foreign Key Table: " VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                            <ComboBox Width="200"  Height="20" Name="fkTabSel" IsEnabled="False" SelectionChanged="fkTabSel_SelectionChanged"/>

                            <Label Content="Foreign Key Column: " VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                            <ComboBox Width="200"  Height="20" Name="fkColSel" IsEnabled="False"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        -->
                    </Grid>

                </TabItem>

            </TabControl>
        </GroupBox>


        <GroupBox Header="Mappings" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="10">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="11*"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <ListBox Name="mappingsListb" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                </ListBox>

                <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Remove Mapping" Width="120" Height="20" />
            </Grid>

        </GroupBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private XDocument? xmlDoc;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Buttons

        private void SelectXmlFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
                openFileDialog.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
                openFileDialog.Title = "Select XML File";
                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    xmlSource.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
                    LoadXmlDocument(openFileDialog.FileName); // Load the XML document
                    //LoadXmlNodes(); // Populate the TreeView with XML nodes
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error selecting XML file: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }


        private void SelectDatabase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ConnectionWindow connectionWindow = new ConnectionWindow();
                if (connectionWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    connectionString.Text = Config.ConnectionString;
                    LoadDatabaseTablesToComboBox();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error selecting database: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Loads
        private void LoadXmlDocument(string xmlFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
                LoadXsdToEditor();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error loading XML document: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        private void LoadDatabaseTablesToComboBox()
        {
            try
            {
                using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.Text);
                connection.Open();
                var tables = connection.GetSchema("Tables").AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(row => row.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME"))
                    .OrderBy(name => name) // sort alphabetically
                    .ToList();
                tableSel.ItemsSource = tables;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error loading database tables: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        private void LoadDatabaseColumnsToCombobox()
        {
            var selectedTable = tableSel.SelectedItem?.ToString();
            if (selectedTable == null) return;

            try
            {
                using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.Text);
                connection.Open();
                var columns = connection.GetSchema("Columns", new string[] { null, null, selectedTable })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(row => row.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME"))
                    .ToList();
                columnSel.ItemsSource = columns;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error loading table columns: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        private void LoadXsdToEditor()
        {
            try
            {
                using XmlReader reader = xmlDoc.CreateReader();
                XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
                XmlSchemaInference schemaInference = new XmlSchemaInference();
                schemaInference.InferSchema(reader, schemaSet);

                // Retrieve the inferred schema from the XmlSchemaSet object
                XmlSchema? schema = schemaSet.Schemas().Cast<XmlSchema>().FirstOrDefault();

                // Write the schema to textEditor
                using var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                if (schema != null)
                {
                    schema.Write(writer);
                    textEditor.Text = writer.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error generating XSD: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods

        #endregion

        #region Events

        private void tableSel_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadDatabaseColumnsToCombobox();
        }

        private void textEditor_DocumentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        #endregion

    }
```

Config.cs

```
namespace XSD_Mapper
{
    internal class Config
    {
        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MappingData.cs

```
    public class MappingData
    {
        public string? ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public List<Mapping>? Mappings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mapping
    {
        public string? TableName { get; set; }
        public List<Column>? Columns { get; set; }
    }

    public class Column
    {
        public string? ColumnName { get; set; }
        public string? XmlNodePath { get; set; }
    }
```

---

Edit:

Method that would generate the mappings:

```
        private MappingData mappingData = new();

        private void AddMapping_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             try
            {
                var selectedTable = tableSel.SelectedItem?.ToString();
                var selectedColumn = columnSel.SelectedItem?.ToString();
                var selectedNode = xmlNodes.SelectedItem?.ToString();
                if (selectedTable == null || selectedColumn == null || selectedNode == null) return;
                var mapping = new Mapping
                {
                    TableName = selectedTable,
                    Columns = new List<Column>
                    {
                        new Column
                        {
                            ColumnName = selectedColumn,
                            XmlNodePath = selectedNode
                        }
                    }
                };
                mappingData.Mappings ??= new List<Mapping>();
                mappingData.Mappings.Add(mapping);
                mappingsListb.Items.Add(mapping.TableName + " " + mapping.Columns);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error adding mapping: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
```

Resultant JSON File after modifications:

```
{
  "ConnectionString": **********,
  "Mappings": [
    {
      "TableName": "XMLOrder",
      "Columns": [
        {
          "ColumnName": "OrderId",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/OrderId",
          "Parent": null
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "OrderNumber",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/OrderNumber",
          "Parent": null
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "CustomerId",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/Customer/CustomerId",
          "Parent": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "TableName": "XMLCustomer",
      "Columns": [
        {
          "ColumnName": "CustomerId",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/Customer/CustomerId",
          "Parent": null
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "Name",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/Customer/Name",
          "Parent": null
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "Address",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/Customer/Address",
          "Parent": null
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "City",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/Customer/City",
          "Parent": null
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "State",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/Customer/State",
          "Parent": null
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "Zip",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/Customer/Zip",
          "Parent": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "TableName": "XMLItem",
      "Columns": [
        {
          "ColumnName": "ItemId",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/Items/Item/ItemId",
          "Parent": null
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "OrderId",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/OrderId",
          "Parent": null
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "Name",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/Items/Item/Name",
          "Parent": null
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "Quantity",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/Items/Item/Quantity",
          "Parent": null
        },
        {
          "ColumnName": "Price",
          "XmlNodePath": "Orders/Order/Items/Item/Price",
          "Parent": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry in advance if I haven't been clear with my question or any of the doubts I displayed, this is my first time asking for help here and english isn't my first language. If you have any question that would help towards the solution of the matter I will try to respond ASP and try to be clear and concise.

Comment: Also, I'm not married to this system, I know of the existance of the SQLXML Bulk Load tool, but I'm not familiar with it's usage, or if it's the tool I need for the final purpose of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// **Edit 2)** *I'm attaching an example to your subquestion in your comment*:

```
private void AddMapping_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var selectedTable = tableSel.SelectedItem?.ToString();
        var selectedColumn = columnSel.SelectedItem?.ToString();
        var selectedNode = xmlNodes.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem; // Changed to TreeViewItem

        if (selectedTable == null || selectedColumn == null || selectedNode == null) return;

        mappingData.Mappings ??= new List<Mapping>();
        var existingMapping = mappingData.Mappings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.TableName == selectedTable);

        var isRepeating = CheckIfRepeating(selectedNode); // Check if the node is repeating

        if (existingMapping != null)
        {
            // Mapping already exists for this table, add new column to it
            existingMapping.Columns.Add(new Column
            {
                ColumnName = selectedColumn,
                XmlNodePath = GetXmlNodePath(selectedNode),
                IsRepeating = isRepeating
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // No existing mapping for this table, create a new one
            var mapping = new Mapping
            {
                TableName = selectedTable,
                Columns = new List<Column>
                {
                    new Column
                    {
                        ColumnName = selectedColumn,
                        XmlNodePath = GetXmlNodePath(selectedNode),
                        IsRepeating = isRepeating
                    }
                }
            };
            mappingData.Mappings.Add(mapping);
        }

        // Refresh the ListBox
        mappingsListb.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var mapping in mappingData.Mappings)
        {
            foreach (var column in mapping.Columns)
            {
                mappingsListb.Items.Add($"{mapping.TableName} {column.ColumnName} -> {column.XmlNodePath} {(column.IsRepeating ? "[Repeating]" : "")}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error adding mapping: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}

private string GetXmlNodePath(TreeViewItem item)
{
    var path = item.Header.ToString();
    var parent = item.Parent as TreeViewItem;
    while (parent != null)
    {
        path = parent.Header + "/" + path;
        parent = parent.Parent as TreeViewItem;
    }
    return path;
}

private bool CheckIfRepeating(TreeViewItem item)
{
    // Implement the logic to check if an item is repeating in XML.
    // If an item has siblings with the same name, it's a repeating item.
    // For simplicity, let's assume that you can check the 'Items' property of the parent TreeViewItem.
    var parent = item.Parent as TreeViewItem;
    if (parent == null) return false;
    var siblingNames = parent.Items.Cast<TreeViewItem>().Select(i => i.Header.ToString()).ToList();
    return siblingNames.Count(n => n == item.Header.ToString()) > 1;
}
```

The idea here is to check if a node has siblings with the same name, which would typically indicate that the node represents an element that is repeated within its parent element. However, the exact logic could be different depending on how you've finally structured your TreeView.

The GetXmlNodePath function constructs the XML node path by traversing up the TreeView from the selected item to the root. This assumes that each TreeViewItem's Header property corresponds to an XML node name, and the hierarchy of TreeViewItems reflects the XML document's structure.

In the AddMapping_Click function, we're first checking if a Mapping for the selected table already exists. If it does, we add a new Column to it; otherwise, we create a new Mapping and add it to the Mappings list.

Finally, we're updating how the mappings are displayed in the ListBox. Now each mapping includes an indication of whether or not the corresponding XML element is repeating, based on the IsRepeating property.

Remember to update your Column class to include the IsRepeating property:

```
public class Column
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string XmlNodePath { get; set; }
    public bool IsRepeating { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
}
```

This will include the IsRepeating field in your JSON output, which your reader program can then use to handle repeating XML elements correctly.
I hope this helps you. I don't want to do all the specific code for you, I just hope it guides you to where you need to go and you work it all out yourself, it's always better that way. Cheers.

// **Edit 1)** *for answering to your edited code*:
The logic in your AddMapping_Click method is good for a basic mapping scenario where you map a single table/column to an XML node. However, to handle more complex mappings where a table may have multiple columns that each map to different XML nodes, or where XML nodes have a parent-child relationship, you need to modify the logic a bit.

One way to do this is to first check if a mapping for the selected table already exists. If it does, add the new column to that mapping's Columns list. If it doesn't, create a new mapping with the selected table and column.

Here's how you might modify your AddMapping_Click method to handle this:

```
private void AddMapping_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var selectedTable = tableSel.SelectedItem?.ToString();
        var selectedColumn = columnSel.SelectedItem?.ToString();
        var selectedNode = xmlNodes.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem; // Changed to TreeViewItem

        if (selectedTable == null || selectedColumn == null || selectedNode == null) return;

        mappingData.Mappings ??= new List<Mapping>();
        var existingMapping = mappingData.Mappings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.TableName == selectedTable);

        if (existingMapping != null)
        {
            // Mapping already exists for this table, add new column to it
            existingMapping.Columns.Add(new Column
            {
                ColumnName = selectedColumn,
                XmlNodePath = GetXmlNodePath(selectedNode)
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // No existing mapping for this table, create a new one
            var mapping = new Mapping
            {
                TableName = selectedTable,
                Columns = new List<Column>
                {
                    new Column
                    {
                        ColumnName = selectedColumn,
                        XmlNodePath = GetXmlNodePath(selectedNode)
                    }
                }
            };
            mappingData.Mappings.Add(mapping);
        }

        // Refresh the ListBox
        mappingsListb.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var mapping in mappingData.Mappings)
        {
            foreach (var column in mapping.Columns)
            {
                mappingsListb.Items.Add($"{mapping.TableName} {column.ColumnName} -> {column.XmlNodePath}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error adding mapping: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}

private string GetXmlNodePath(TreeViewItem item)
{
    var path = item.Header.ToString();
    var parent = item.Parent as TreeViewItem;
    while (parent != null)
    {
        path = parent.Header + "/" + path;
        parent = parent.Parent as TreeViewItem;
    }
    return path;
}
```

In this version of the method, selectedNode is a TreeViewItem, not a string. This allows you to use the Parent property of TreeViewItem to build a string that represents the XML path of the selected node. This path is then stored in the XmlNodePath property of the Column.

When a mapping is added, the ListBox is cleared and then repopulated with the updated list of mappings. This makes sure that the ListBox always reflects the current state of mappingData.

Comment: Doing good! Thanks for asking, and also, thanks for the response, helped me clear up some thoughts. I'm also having trouble grasping the creation of the mappings itselves. I've edited my question to include the method I've written after your reply but it doesn't take into account stuff like the parent Column, as i'm not completely sure how to handle that. Thanks again for the response and sorry if I'm not completely grasping the concept. Managing XML data is something completely new to me and I've been asked to do this program and dont want to simply give up.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my reply, hope that helps.

Comment: Wow, thanks again. I will perform some tests and come back with the results. Would love to +1 your answer, but dont have the necessary reputation yet!

Comment: Yeah, thx. Someone put two minuses on it without giving any advice, I really like guys like that.

Comment: Alright! Looks like this is going somewhere. I'll add the resultant JSON file to the main question. I guess that after sorting out the parent variable, I'll be able to start development of the reading program. I was thinking that maybe I should somehow indicate what nodes are nested loops, then the reader program's job would be easier (as in less of a headache of developing)

Comment: I'm at the gym right now. I'll check it out later.

Comment: Yes, sure. Again, thank you for the help you're giving me. Here's the [GitHub link](https://github.com/eduardbtic/XSD_Mapper).

I won't be able to try anything this afternoon, but any advise you give, I'll try it out tomorrow morning.

And for real, thanks again, it's been a headache for me to try and make this program. For some reason I just get blocked with this.

Comment: OK I'm here again. Your JSON structure is looking good, and you're right that we can improve it further by indicating the nested loop structure. To indicate what nodes are nested loops, we can add a new boolean property, let's call it bool IsRepeating, in the Column class. This property should be set to true for XML nodes that represent the start of a repeating sequence (i.e., an XML element that can have multiple instances within its parent).
I'll insert a new version of the AddMapping_Click method, as it may look like now.